# Both physical and mental strength(s) is/ are

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I know **strength** is an uncountable noun. But if I want to say:

> Both physical and mental strength(s) is/are important.

As I use **both** here, I’m not sure whether it is **is** or **are** that can be used in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "are"

If you mean  (physical and mental) strength, then you would use "is"  (singular subject with two properties.)  Just like you would say "a red and blue sock is..."

However using "both" suggests you actually mean "Physical strength and mental strength"  (two different types of strength) so you would use "are".

Comment: Do I have to write “both physical strength and mental strength are” or just “both physical and mental strength are”?

Comment: The latter will do fine. The ellipsis is well understood.